# How to count number of grouped rows in the Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I need to count and show number of rows of grouped data in the report. I already have number of rows of total data in Report Footer section (I used Count() function and that works fine), but I need to have total rows in the Group Footer section which shows number of rows of grouped data. The visible explanation of the problem is shown under.

Thanks.

```
----------------------------------------------------
Group 1

        row 1---------------------------  
        row 2---------------------------
        .
        .
        .
        row N---------------------------
--- I need here number of rows!---------------------
----------------------------------------------------
Group 2

        row 1---------------------------  
        row 2---------------------------
        .
        .
        .
        row M---------------------------
--- I need here number of rows!---------------------
----------------------------------------------------
Total Rows: M+N
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the solution

1. Create a formula `@reset`. Place the formula in `groupheader` and `supress`

   ```
    Shared Numbervar count;
    count:=0
   ```
2. Now create one more formula `@ Increment` and place in section where there are `rows` I have assumed it as detail section and `supress`.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   count:=count+1;
   count;
   ```
3. Now create one more formula `@Display`. Place this formula in `Group footer`

   ```
   Shared Numbervar count;
   Shared Numbervar Count_Final;
   Count_Final:=Count_Final+count;
   count;
   ```
4. Now create  one more formula `@DisplayFinal` and place in `Report Footer`

   ```
   Shared Numbervar Count_Final;
   Count_Final
   ```

Answer (score 6):

This solution may help someone,

**Create a Running Total:**

1. Choose a field
2. Select **distinct count** as Type of summary
3. Choose your group name in Reset section
4. Now drag and drop the running total field in group footer.

Refer the image below
[image]

Comment: What if I have more than one group I want to count but want to show two running totals in the same row (e.g. Group Footer 1)? I have two running total rows within Group Footer 2.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem
Create new formula field

{IM_INV.QTY_ON_HND}-{IM_INV.QTY_ON_HND}+1

{Existing field} minus {exiting field} plus 1

This gave me a "1" next to each detail line in a field I called {NumberForCount}

Because it was made this way it showed up in running total field options

Then made a running total field like normal in the footer

Comment: I was working with Crystal Reports a long time ago. I solved my problem. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to try by using Summary

1. Right Click > Insert > Summary
2. Choose Field (I choose string
   value)
3. Choose "Count" to Calculate This Summary Combo box
4. Choose Summary Location in Where would you like to show this total
5. Then OK