# Crystal Reports grouping with group name in one row with group items

Tags: crystal-reports

Need to group and show data in Crystal Reports (Visual Studio 2017) in this way

```
---------------------------------------
              | item1 of this group
Group value 1 | item2 of this group
              | item3 of this group
---------------------------------------
              | item1 of this group
Group value 2 | item2 of this group
              | item3 of this group
---------------------------------------
```

and so on.
But, as I see so far, Group name always placed ABOVE group's items.

Is it possible to format report as in my example above? How?

Comment: You could insert a subreport in the group header and link the main and sub report with the key of the group. For each header the sub report will show its items

Comment: @Raphael 's idea is the best for the example you gave, but if you're ok with having the group name on each row, the easier solution would be to put the group name in a column in the details section. Personally I like this method as lots of reports are exported to Excel. Null rows make it tough to filter in Excel. His solution is pretty simple too and more precise to your written goal.

Comment: Antoher thing that you could do if you want to implement @Jackson solution, that surely is the easier and faster one, is to insert a group row counter, and show the group label just for the first row and suppress it for the other. here you can find how to creare a row counter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509119/how-to-count-number-of-grouped-rows-in-the-crystal-report

Comment: Thanks, guys. Last @Raphael's proposal is the most suitable.